# Build failed for no visualized reason

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate`. I didn't use that about 1 day (which means I didn't manipulate anything on the suite) and currently when I want to compile and run every `C#` project through VS I get stopped by no error other than:

> Build failed

With no further explanation or visual clue. I even checked the `Developer CMD for VS2013` to test if the compiler itself is working and it was. I have a shallow knowledge about the VS build system and cannot find out what happened. What should I do?

Thanks

UPDATE 1:

Here's the output:
[image]

UPDATE 2:
Here's an exra-line from the output when I set the verbosity (from Tools) to `diagnostic`.

> 1>Project 'ConsoleApplication18' is not up to date. Input file 'c:\users\amin\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication18\consoleapplication18\program.cs' is modified after output file 'c:\users\amin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication18\ConsoleApplication18\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication18.pdb'.

Comment: What does the output window say?

Comment: Are you saying that there is no additional output in the `Output` window?

Comment: Try enhancing the verbose level.

Comment: I've appended the output in the post.

Comment: Can you build the solution using MsBuild from a Visual Studio command prompt ? Are there any post build actions ?  I suspect one of the post-build actions is failing

Comment: Have you try rebooting your computer ?

Comment: You might consider increasing the build output verbosity to better understand what's going on.  There are options for this under Tools/Options : Projects and Solutions/Build and Run.

Comment: @JacodeGroot Yes. I can.

Comment: I've added the extra info to the post after changing the verbosity.

Comment: This appears to be a machine specific issue, perhaps extensions or addins, according to the official Microsoft Bug Post here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785601/pdbs-make-my-project-always-out-of-date

Comment: just covering the bases here, but have you cleaned and built? or just built?

Comment: @DylanCorriveau both clean and build fails for every new project.

Comment: It could have something to do with your anti-virus. It may be detecting the new/intermediate files and removing them. Try disabling your av.

Comment: @Mathemats Tried that. Not worked.